# Using `opt` combinator in uu-parsinglib

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am writing a parser for a simple text template language for my project, and I am completely stuck on `opt` combinator in uu-parsinglib (version 2.7.3.2 in case that matters).  Any ideas on how to use it properly?

Here is a very simplified example that shows my predicament.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Text.ParserCombinators.UU hiding (pEnd)
import Text.ParserCombinators.UU.Utils
import Text.ParserCombinators.UU.BasicInstances

pIdentifier :: Parser String
pIdentifier = pMany pLetter

pIfClause :: Parser ((String, String), String, Maybe (String, String), String)
pIfClause = (,,,) <$> pIf <*> pIdentifier <*> pOptionalElse <*> pEnd

pIf :: Parser (String, String)
pIf = pBraces ((,) <$> pToken "if " <*> pIdentifier)

pOptionalElse :: Parser (Maybe (String, String))
pOptionalElse = (((\x y -> Just (x, y)) <$> pElse <*> pIdentifier) `opt` Nothing)

pElse :: Parser String
pElse = pBraces (pToken "else")

pEnd :: Parser String
pEnd = pBraces (pToken "end")

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ runParser "works" pIfClause "{if abc}def{else}ghi{end}"
  putStrLn $ show $ runParser "doesn't work" pIfClause "{if abc}def{end}"
```

The first string parses properly but the second fails with error:

```
main: Failed parsing 'doesn't work' :
Expected  at position LineColPos 0 12 12 expecting one of [Whitespace, "else"] at LineColPos 0 12 12 :
                              v
                  {if abc}def{end}
                              ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `opt` says:

> If p can be recognized, the return value of p is used. Otherwise, the value v is used. Note that opt by default is greedy.

What greedy means is explained in the documentation for `<<|>`:

> <<|> is the greedy version of <|>. If its left hand side parser can make any progress then it commits to that alternative.

In your case, the first argument to `opt` does recognize part of the input, because `else` and `end` both start with `e`. Thus, it commits to `pElse`, which fails and makes the whole parse fail.

An easy way to solve this is to use `... <|> pure Nothing`, as the documentation suggests.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I tried it but apparently not.  "<|> pure Nothing" works.